# Differences between NetBeans Git integration and git command line

Tags: git, netbeans

I am just now trying to learn Git; both the git command line application (henceforth, simply "Git") as well as the Git integration in NetBeans (henceforth, simply "NetBeans"). From what I can tell, only some of the actions performed within NetBeans actually show up in Git. It is as if NetBeans has its own separate Staging area (AKA: Index), and built-in .gitignore file.

For instance: When I first initialize a repository in my project folder, git status at the command line gives me:

```
D:\Dev\Learning\Experiments\StupidLoopPrinter>git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        build.xml
        build/
        manifest.mf
        nbproject/
        src/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

However, when I turn on View/Show Versioning Labels in NetBeans and then look at the Files tree in NetBeans, I see that many files are marked as being "Added" and others are marked as being "Ignored" (even though there is no .gitignore file in the project folder) when I hover over the filenames in the tree.

Still yet, when I right-click on my project node then chose Git / Show Changes (oddly not available under the Team menu), the pane that opens up at the bottom of the NetBeans window does not show any "Changes between HEAD and Index," essentially telling me the same thing as the git status command.

So, I right-clicked on my one .java file in NetBeans and chose Git/Add. Now my git status shows:

```
D:\Dev\Learning\Experiments\StupidLoopPrinter>git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   src/StupidLoopPrinter.java

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        build.xml
        build/
        manifest.mf
        nbproject/
```

... and StupidLoopPrinter.java shows up in "Changes between HEAD and Index."

Upon closer inspection of the markers to the right of all my files in the NetBeans File Tree, I see that the StupidLoopPrinter.java file has a [A/-] next to it, whereas all the other files have a [-/A] next to them. What is the significance of that difference? (As you can imagine, that is impossible to google.)

Finally: Why does NetBeans show files as being "Added" or "Ignored" when git status just shows them as neither added nor ignored? Does NetBeans, in fact, keep its own, internal, ignore list and staging area? If so, why the heck isn't this documented?

================= UPDATE ================
I have run commit by choosing Team/Commit in the NetBeans menu. As predicted, that did change the stage as far as the git command is concerned. git status gives me:

```
D:\Dev\Learning\Experiments\StupidLoopPrinter>git status
On branch Alice
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   src/StupidLoopPrinter.java

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        build/
        nbproject/private/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Notice that several files shown as "untracked" above are not shown as "untracked" here. However, NetBeans did NOT create a .gitignore file.

Comment: What you saw initially in NetBeans may be a one time thing.  I don't know the plugin, but it should mirror what the Git bash command line tool is showing you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Nope. I have exited Netbeans and restarted. Everything is still the same. Now, I suspect that if I use NetBeans to do a commit, then it may modify the git staging area as well as create a .gitignore file to match what NetBeans is showing in the interface. However, I want to take this one step at a time. My goal is not to just be able to do a commit. I want to be able to know exactly what NetBeans is doing so I can write about it to teach others and help them avoid these pitfalls. I will try that experiment and make further comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Netbeans File sTatus Information](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#viewFileStatus):

> The IDE displays two status values for a file:
>
> - A status describing differences between the files Index state and current HEAD commit.
> - A status describing differences between the files Working Tree and Index state,

So:

> `StupidLoopPrinter.java` file has a `[A/-]` next to it, whereas all the other files have a `[-/A]`

That means:

- `StupidLoopPrinter.java` is a new file, added to the index.
- the other files are new files, not yet added to the index (ie untracked)

For ignored file, try in command-line a:

```
git check-ignore -v -- an-ignored-file
```

You will see if there is a `.gitignore` or `core.excludesfile` setting which would explain that status.

Comment: I have read the linked-to documentation. However, now I see that the two statuses are separated by a slash. So, [-/A] (on all the files I did not manually add) means "No difference between stage and commit" with the dash on the left of the slash, and " 'added' to my working directory but not staged" with the A to the right of the slash. I guess that latter also has the additional meaning of "and NetBeans plans to put it in the next commit even though you haven't told NetBeans specifically to do so."

Comment: @GrantRobertson "not staged" means it will not be part of the next git commit though.

Comment: While what you say is true for the git command, it seems to mean something different to NetBeans. See my secondary answer, below.

Answer (score 0):

As a secondary answer, I would like to add that NetBeans does not seem to actually have its own stage. Instead, it merely marks certain files for inclusion in the next commit. This "marking" is only known to NetBeans. So, once a NetBeans project folder is initialized for Git (using either the git command or the NetBeans interface) then what ends up in the first commit depends on whether you use the git command or the NetBeans interface. If you use the git command and merely enter

```
git init
git commit
```

...you will end up with nothing in your commit.

However, if you use NetBeans to do the commit, then it will automatically take all the files it has marked with [-/A] and add them to the stage for you, then do the commit. All those files will then be considered "tracked" and the git command will notice if your working files change. NetBeans will also ignore all those files it has marked with [I] but this information will not be conveyed to the git command via a .gitignore file. Rather, NetBeans merely depends upon that fact that those files are untracked to keep them out of future commits you may make with the git command. I expect the writers of the NetBeans Git plugin were assuming that we would always use the NetBeans interface and never use the git command.